# Bind event to ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, events, xaml, mvvm

I am using WPF and PRISM framework for my application. The pattern I am using is MVVM (Model - View - ViewModel) and I am trying to bring the MouseLeftButtonUp event from the code-behind in the View to the ViewModel (so the event will be according the MVVM rules). For now I have this:

View.xaml:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="employeeGrid" Height="250" Margin="25,0,10,0" ItemsSource="{Binding DetacheringenEmployeesModel}" IsReadOnly="True" ColumnHeaderStyle="{DynamicResource CustomColumnHeader}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeight="30">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                 <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding EmployeeGrid_MouseLeftButtonUp}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
<DataGrid.Columns>
```

View.xaml.cs (code-behind):

```
public partial class UC1001_DashBoardConsultants_View
{
    public UC1001_DashBoardConsultants_View(UC1001_DashboardConsultantViewModel viewModel)
    {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

ViewModel.cs:

```
 public void EmployeeGrid_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
 {
     // insert logic here
 }
```

The main idea is, when I click on a cell in the DataGrid, the event will fire. I first tried it in the code behind, and it worked. I got so far with the EventTriggers, but when I debug and click on a cell, my debugger doesn't come into the method.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

PS: Does it also work with the (object sender) parameter when I do it like that? Because I need the DataGrid in my ViewModel to get the ActiveCell I just clicked on.

**EDIT:**

The event-binding worked with the Command!

I have this in my DataGrid:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Okt" Width="*" x:Name="test" >
     <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
           <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
             <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding Months[9].AgreementID}"/>
```

How can I bind the Tag property to the ViewModel? I know it's already bound from the ViewModel, but as you can see the value comes from an Array/List and per column the value is different.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[InvokeCommandAction](http://InvokeCommandAction) requires the `ICommand` to be bound not an event handler as you've bound (EmployeeGrid_MouseLeftButtonUp).

So you can introduce a command in ViewModel and bind to it:

**View Model:**

```
public ICommand SomeActionCommand { get; set; }
```

**XAML:**

```
<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SomeActionCommand}" />
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! Do you also have a suggestion to pass the DataGrid along with the command (as a parameter or something) so I can access it in my ViewModel?

Comment: @Jelle Capenberghs : no, passing an entire UI container in ViewModel is not the MVVM approach, ViewModel should not know anything about specific UI implementation (today you're usign rid, but perhaps tomorrow - TreeView so ViewModel has to be refactored, this is wrong). What are you trying to do in this command?

Comment: I need to get the Cell I clicked in my ViewModel because the Cell contains a TextBlock with information I need in the ViewModel. - Already marked as answer because the ICommand was primarly what I needed!

Comment: I would suggest binding text itself `<TextBox Text="{Binding ViewModelProperty}" >` rather than such complext scenario with events

Comment: Could someone please tell me what namespace is "i"?

Comment: Google for "Interaction.Behavuiours"