# WPF Change Background Color from Textbox

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, background-color

I want to change the Background Color of a textbox object. I'm using the mvvm pattern and have in my model a property TextBoxColor that is binded to the textbox background property.
Thats not the problem. now i want that the color changes if i write text in the textbox, but the textbox has no command so i don't know a way to check if there is text in the textbox and change the background color property.

can anyone tell me a solution?

Comment: change the color on KeyDown and back on LostFocus

Comment: i don't want to use code behind

Comment: I understand, but it sure sounds like pure View code which to me makes sense to be in the view layer.

Comment: consider this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929611/bind-event-to-viewmodel-wpf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to bin the text-property of the textbox to a property in the viewmodel.
The code for the binding should look like

```
<TextBox Text={Binding TextBoxText, Mode="TwoWay", UpdateSourceTrigger="OnPropertyChanged"/>
```

In the setter of the viewModel you can react on the changed value