# Adding GridViewColumnHeader.Click to a GridView created in a class

Tags: c#, wpf, class, gridview

I'm writing an application that is creating most of the WPF interface with C#. When the user double-clicks a node in a tree view, an instance is created of a class I designed.

That class handles everything else - creating a ListView control and a GridView, setting the ListView view to the GridView, and finally creating a new TabItem, populating it with the ListView, and adding the TabItem to a pre-existing TabControl.

I'm running into problems adding a GridViewColumn.Click event handler to my ListView, because I want the function for the click event to be in my main window class, not the separate class that creates the ListView and GridView.

I've figured out how to use `ref` to reference the TabControl in my WPF window from my separate class, but what about functions? How can I add a click event handler in my class that references a function in the main window class?

Comment: Pass a reference to the handler in the ctor.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a command instead of a event handler. Then you can bind the command to whichever class you want to handle it

check [Bind event to ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929611/bind-event-to-viewmodel-wpf)

Comment: I ended up just moving the event handler to the same class that contains the actual ListView and GridView, and everything works now. I don't know if that's really best practice, though..