# Bind events to Item ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a ListView/GridView setup and I want to handle a right click on the dislayed items. Is there are Databinding-way of doing this? I have seen complicated workarounds like [handling the super-elements event](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2008/12/02/wpf-datagrid-detecting-clicked-cell-and-row.html) [and poking around to find its origin](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/22373fc7-c677-46a1-80ff-3e262836ecc1/right-click-in-wpf-datagrid), but that feels awfully bloated for such basic request.

What I'd love to see is something like binding the event to an action of the item's ViewModel - is there a way to do that? Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929611/bind-event-to-viewmodel-wpf), but I can't quite wrap my head around how to adapt that to work on a single ListView item (I am not even sure that's possible, tbh).

Rough outline:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView />
    </ListView.View>
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
</ListView/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way using the Interactivity assembly form the Blend SDK. It will provide an `EventTrigger` which executes a command when an event is raised.

```
<!--
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
-->

<Button Content="Click me">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

**Edit:**

A possible solution for your problem could look like this:

View:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseRightButtonUp">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RightClickOnItemCommand}"
                                   CommandParameter={Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=listView} />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListView>
```

ViewModel:

```
public ICommand RightClickOnItemCommand { get; set; }

public void RightClickOnItem(object item)
{
}
```

Comment: This sure looks like it's what I want, but how would I apply this? Would this work via the style? If you could try to incorporate this into the snippet I added to the question, that'd be grand.

Comment: I added a possible solution for you specific problem.

Comment: This took some time to understand properly, but this is *exactly* what I wanted; thanks a lot & have my accept!

Answer (score 1):

You could try to create a style template for the list view item, and add an attached behaviour to it to handle mouse clicks.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownCommand", typeof (ICommand),
            typeof (MouseBehaviour), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownCommandChanged));

    private static void PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownCommandChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var element = (FrameworkElement) dependencyObject;
        element.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += Element_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;
    }

    private static void Element_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs args)
    {
        var element = (FrameworkElement) sender;
        ICommand command = GetPreviewMouseLeftButtonDownCommand(element);
        if (command != null)
        {
            command.Execute(args);
        }
    }

    public static void SetPreviewMouseLeftButtonDownCommand(UIElement element, ICommand value)
    {
        element.SetValue(PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownCommandProperty, value);
    }

    public static ICommand GetPreviewMouseLeftButtonDownCommand(UIElement element)
    {
        return (ICommand) element.GetValue(PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownCommandProperty);
    }
```