# Filter clicks on Column Header

Tags: wpf, xaml, blend

I am using a construct as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674786/bind-events-to-item-viewmodel) earlier question of mine, which looks something like

```xml
<ListView x:Name="listView">

    <ListView.View>
        <GridView />
    </ListView.View>

    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}"/>
    </ListView.Resources>

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseRightButtonUp">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RightClickOnItemCommand}"
                                   CommandParameter={Binding SelectedItem,
                                                     ElementName=listView} />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListView>
```

This works like a charm, except it fires when I right-click on the column headers. Since I only get the SelectedItem as a parameter for the command and the selected item property doesn't clear when you click a header (and I don't want it to, either), I don't  see a way to fix this problem on the viewmodel side.

Until now, I really liked this solution, since it provides a really nice and clean way to handle those events, but this corner case drives me crazy.

I know I could add an event setter to the `ListViewItem` Style, but the handler would then in turn require me to write code-behind, which I wanted to avoid in the first place, hence the `System.Windows.Interactivity`-Stuff.

Is there an equally nice and clean way to prevent that from happening (i.e. a way that does not involve me writing ugly code-behind hacks)?

Comment: you could put the EventTrigger in the ListViewItems via `ItemContainerStyle`.

Comment: @HighCore I am not sure I understand. I can't add the triggers to the `<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}"/>` since, as Intellisense tells me, they can only be added to something that derives from dependency object. I might be going over it all wrong though, I don't have an awful lot of experience developing with WPF.

Comment: @HighCore I think I do understand what you meant now, but it would have required the same workaround to allow for triggers in styles that I featured in my answer, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved with the method described [here](http://vspivak.wordpress.com/2011/01/19/using-system-windows-interactivity-behaviors-and-actions-in-wpfsilverlight-styles/). The class that is developed in the article essentially adds an attached property to hold the triggers.

```cs
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TemplateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Template", 
        typeof(InteractivityTemplate), 
        typeof(InteractivityItems),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(InteractivityTemplate), OnTemplateChanged));

    private static void OnTemplateChanged(
        DependencyObject d, 
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        InteractivityTemplate dt = (InteractivityTemplate)e.NewValue;
        dt.Seal();
        InteractivityItems ih = (InteractivityItems)dt.LoadContent();
        BehaviorCollection bc = Interaction.GetBehaviors(d);
        TriggerCollection tc = Interaction.GetTriggers(d);

        foreach (Behavior behavior in ih.Behaviors)
            bc.Add(behavior);

        foreach (TriggerBase trigger in ih.Triggers)
            tc.Add(trigger);
    }
```

This now allows to add triggers to the individual items:

```xml
<ListView.Resources>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
       <Setter Property="int:InteractivityItems.Template">
           <Setter.Value>
               <int:InteractivityTemplate>
                   <int:InteractivityItems>
                       <int:InteractivityItems.Triggers>
                           <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseRightButtonUp">
                               <i:InvokeCommandAction 
                                  Command="{Binding RightClickCommand}" />
                           </i:EventTrigger>
                       </int:InteractivityItems.Triggers>
                   </int:InteractivityItems>
                </int:InteractivityTemplate>
           </Setter.Value>
       </Setter>
   </Style>
</ListView.Resources>
```

This actually models the idea of clicking an item instead of clicking on the list and finding the item that was below the pointer when the list was clicked.